# Why cloud function sometimes overwrites a document, but sometimes merges the data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have firestore collection with documents. And I wrote a cloud function to aggregate the documents into one doc with an array of objects.

The problem is that when the function is first triggered, it creates a new document (for aggregated data) or rewrites the existing one. But then with the data changes, the function only merges new data to existing one. So with only two documents in the collection within 25 changes the aggregation document will be expanded to 50 items in the array (instead of expected two).

But then, if I wait some time (10-20 minutes) and try again, the function finally rewrites the document. And then merges data again.

Had anyone such a problem?
How to say to firestore that the doc should strictly be rewritten?

I have tried update, set(data, {merge: false}) methods, the result is the same. Tried to first delete the document and then create a new one, but firestore behaves inadequately, it sometimes deletes, but sometimes creates the doc.

```
exports.aggregateTracks = functions.firestore
  .document('playlists/{playlistId}/tracks/{trackId}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
     const playlistId = context.params.playlistId;
     const trackId = context.params.trackId;

     const docRef = admin.firestore().collection('playlists').doc(playlistId);

     docRef.collection('tracks').orderBy('likes', 'desc')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {

        trackCount = querySnapshot.size;
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        tracks.push(doc.data());
        });

    resultRef = admin.firestore().collection('playlists').doc(playlistId)
        .collection('trackAggregation').doc('trackAggregation');

    var FieldValue = admin.firestore.FieldValue;
    var data = {
        count: trackCount,
        tracks: tracks,
        timestamp: FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
    };

    resultRef.set(data);

    return docRef;
    }).catch(err => console.log(err));

  return null;
});
```

I expect that the document is rewritten everytime the function .set() the data.

Comment: You're ignoring the promise returned by set().  Your function needs to return a promise that resolves only after all the async work is complete, otherwise it will likely shut down and clean up the function before that work is complete.

Comment: Doug is right!!